# Webtoon with a female who is reincarnated and not the female lead. She has a black-haired friend (slave) and in the school they find a magical book!

Tags: story-identification, reincarnation, webcomics

The female lead has bright hair and the boy was a black-haired slave? They went to school and she has to help/avoid the female lead (sister) but enters a hidden room with the black-haired boy, where they find a magical book that went inside her body. Then the dean comes to "rescue" the kids and ask if something else was in the now empty room, which they denied.

Does someone know this comic?? I really miss the story but couldn't find it again.

Comment: "She has a black-haired friend (slave)." That's like number 3 on "tell me that it's an isekai without telling me that it is an isekai," after "overpowered skill that seems weak" and "attractive harem devoted to the protagonist." Actually, it is probably part of #2.

Comment: I'm a little confused about who you are referring to as the "female lead" and who is "she". Is this right? The webtoon has a female lead with bright hair (call her A). And there is a female character (not the female lead) who was reincarnated (call her B). B has a friend who is a slave, a boy with black hair (C). A, B and C all attend school together. Then you mention A is a sister - B's sister? And B and C enter a hidden room to avoid A, where they find a magic book? By lead, do you mean A is the lead of this webtoon, or is this one of those "reincarnated into a story" deals?

Comment: Im not sure if B is reincarnated or in a novel, (but i guess novel)  it wasnt completly clear (for me), A is her sister as i remember, both of them have bright hair.. and C has black hair. C had a poor life "before" and she knew about it and so took him in.. It was like 4 years ago that i read it, it was by far not completed, and i tend to wait before i look again at those comics, but my Ipad got stolen and with it my library in the comic app that does not run anymore.